# How to checkout and build solution

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have a C# solution in Git. How can I checkout (clone+checkout branch) to a fresh directory and then call msbuild on it?

I use the Admin developer command prompt 2015, and git clone and checkout works fine but msbuild gives me tons of errors. References + nuget libraries are not resolved it seems.

I can't find any options in MSBuild that resolves this for me. My goal is to have a script that automates checkout and build to a fresh directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build a solution within Visual Studio, it handles doing the additional steps like NuGet Package Restore for you automatically, in addition to calling msbuild to actually compile the solution.  However, these are two distinct steps.

When you attempt to compile the solution outside of Visual Studio, then you are going to need to handle these two distinct steps.

For example, you are likely going to need to run:

```
nuget restore ./path to sln file.sln
```

And then after that, you will then call MSBuild, passing in the arguments needed to make it work for your solution.

From a personal point of view, I like to script these things out.  There are lots of systems out there that can help with this, including things like psake, fake, rake, etc.  Personally, I like [Cake](http://cakebuild.net/), but I would suggest that you try them out to see what one best suits your needs.  An example build.cake script can be found [here](https://github.com/cake-build/example/blob/master/build.cake).  As you will see, this includes all the "additional" steps that Visual Studio might otherwise do for you.

Comment: Awesome! Was afraid that I would have to spend all days inside the Studio... I now feel the fresh air of the terminal! I didnt have nuget (the command line app), only the VSIX extension, but now that is fixed. I guess this is more popular than products like Maven, Ant, Gradle etc that I am using in the open source landscape?

Comment: btw: my solution contains 54 projects.... do you know where I can find a cake template that helps me build them? Preferrably in the correct order too...

Comment: It is not an easy question to answer.  All of those products do what they do, and do it well, it is just that they might not do what you want.  For my own personal tastes, I want the build script that I am writing to be in the same language as the underlying application I am writing, in my case C#.  Full disclosure, I am one of the maintainers of the Cake project, so I am a little biased there :-)

Comment: Normally, you would have a solution file, an *.sln, which is what you would use to build all those projects.  The inter-project dependencies would be what would control the order that the projects are built.  As a result, a Cake example would be the same as the example link that I showed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nuget restore` before the msbuild ;).